# Automating removal of useless attachment metadata after deleting WordPress's additional image sizes

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Some 4.8.x version of WordPress has silently decided I'm in need of additional images to every one I have already uploaded to its media library. While I'm absolutely not.

I have prevented any future creation of additional images in WP's media library by adding the following code to my `functions.php`:

```
// Prevent WordPress from generating additional image sizes
function shapeSpace_customize_image_sizes($sizes) {
    unset($sizes['thumbnail']);
    unset($sizes['medium']);
    unset($sizes['medium_large']);
    unset($sizes['large']);
    return $sizes;
}
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'shapeSpace_customize_image_sizes');
add_filter('max_srcset_image_width', create_function('', 'return 1;'));
```

At least I hope I have prevented this unneeded for me feature. Have I?

Now I have to delete any useless image, which is not a problem also.

The problem is to remove useless metadata from the WP's MySQL database. I have about 700 images, that's why I prefer not to do it manually.

What MySQL query will help me to do that with a couple of clicks?

I believe I have to batch edit the **_wp_attachment_metadata** column of the **wp_postmeta** table, removing any part of the string that contains `-100x100.jpg` (or `-700x700.jpg` in my particular table, or any other size) part.

Here is the content of a sample cell

```
a:5:
    {s:5:"width";i:700;s:6:"height";i:700;s:4:"file";s:65:"IMAGE1.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:2:
        {s:29:"woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail";a:4:
            {s:4:"file";s:73:"IMAGE1-100x100.jpg";s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:100;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}
        s:18:"woocommerce_single";a:4:
            {s:4:"file";s:73:"IMAGE1-700x700.jpg";s:5:"width";i:700;s:6:"height";i:700;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}
        }
        s:10:"image_meta";a:12:{s:8:"aperture";s:1:"0";s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";s:1:"0";s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";s:1:"0";s:3:"iso";s:1:"0";s:13:"shutter_speed";s:1:"0";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:11:"orientation";s:1:"0";s:8:"keywords";a:0:{}
        }
    }
```

Am I right thinking I should free every cell in **_wp_attachment_metadata** column from

```
    {s:29:"woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail";a:4:
        {s:4:"file";s:73:"IMAGE1-100x100.jpg";s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:100;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}
    s:18:"woocommerce_single";a:4:
        {s:4:"file";s:73:"IMAGE1-700x700.jpg";s:5:"width";i:700;s:6:"height";i:700;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}
    }
```

Can I do that by stating only `-100x100.jpg` or `-700x700.jpg` in the query?

Finally, what the query should look like?

---

PS: I see that WooCommerce is the only one who requires those additional images.

PPS: Too big question. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: I have answered your similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52113456/3354912). Check it out. Hope it helps.