# Remove unneeded Woocommerce image meta

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

A couple of versions ago WOOCommerce has started to generate additional image thumbnails, in my case 100x100 and 700x700 (*700x700 is actually the default image size for my WordPress installation so I don't get the idea of making additional copy*).

To prevent this I've added the following code to my `functions.php`:

```
function shapeSpace_customize_image_sizes($sizes) {
    unset($sizes['shop_catalog']);
    unset($sizes['shop_single']);
    unset($sizes['shop_thumbnail']);
    unset($sizes['woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail']);
    unset($sizes['woocommerce_single']);
    unset($sizes['woocommerce_thumbnail']);
}
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'shapeSpace_customize_image_sizes');
add_filter('max_srcset_image_width', create_function('', 'return 1;'));
```

and it successfully stops WOOCommerce to spam my server any longer.

So now I want to delete all those -100x100 and -700x700 images but I can't do that as they are referenced in `_wp_attachment_metadata` column of `wp_postmeta` table.

The reference is always placed between `"sizes"` and `"image_meta"`, and looks like

```
"sizes";a:4:{s:18:"woocommerce_single";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:30:"IMAGE-700x700.jpg";s:5:"width";i:700;s:6:"height";i:700;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:29:"woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:30:"IMAGE-100x100.jpg";s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:100;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:11:"shop_single";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:30:"IMAGE-700x700.jpg";s:5:"width";i:700;s:6:"height";i:700;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:14:"shop_thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:30:"IMAGE-100x100.jpg";s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:100;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}}s:10:"image_meta"
```

Very large string, but there is no need to read it, as the actual template is just

```
"sizes";a:4:{SOME_TEXT}s:10:"image_meta"
```

where `a:4` after `"sizes"` goes for the number of thumbnails.

---

I want to find and replace every

```
"sizes";a:4:{SOME_TEXT}s:10:"image_meta"
```

with

```
"sizes";a:0:{}s:10:"image_meta"
```

I can do that manually but don't think it is a good idea for ~1000 images.

Is it possible with MySQL query? If so what it would be?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: RT was the first I've tried to fix this. Unfortunately it doesn't help in my case. I've tried every way. And while I've prevented 100x100 generation it still says I hardly need it but doesn't create. Manual removal of everything inside figure brackets and replacing `a:X` with `a:0` do the thing perfectly, so why not to automate it. And thank you for correcting me with WooCommerce actual name - it is very important information in regard to my question! ;)

Comment: The problem is I wouldn't ask this question in case I can do it myself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Export your database with phpMyAdmin
2. Open it's copy (always make backup) in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)
3. Press CTRL+H to open Replace dialogue
4. Put `"sizes".*."image_meta"` into "**Find what:** " field
5. Put `"sizes";a:0:{}s:10:"image_meta"` into "**Replace with:** " field
6. Tick "**Regular expression**", untick "**. matches newline**"
7. Click "**Find Next**" button and make sure only the desired part of a string is selected
8. If it is, click "**Replace All**" button
9. Import your updated database with phpMyAdmin

Comment: @YKKY, Thank you, this does exactly what I need!

Comment: @cale_b, YKKY's answer does exactly what I have asked, also as you can see from my question (look at the Very large string) additional image sizes belong exclusively to WooCommerce. Finally, if I don't want any additional sizes from WooCommerce then why should I want them from any other plugin or theme? ;) Anyway your solution if it works (haven't tested but sure it does) would be perfect for those who would want to customize thumbnail types they would want to remove, so thank you too!

Comment: @cale_b, the question was how to replace every `"sizes";a:4:{SOME_TEXT}s:10:"image_meta"` in the given database with `"sizes";a:0:{}s:10:"image_meta"`. Wasn't it? Why do you think you know better what @Pimpfru needs? Why do you think @Pimpfru is so stupid and doesn't know this solution will destroy every custom image size?